# Pass elements from the nested list to renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

i want to render the elements of each list to a valuebox.
i am able to show the element of single list like below example (run the code for ex) but not nested list.
what i want is to have valuebox which consist of elements of all list.
Please run the code to get the idea.Thankyou

```
#this should be the result:

1stvaluebox    2ndvaluebox  3rdvaluebox   4thvaluebox
A                 C             E             H
Kim               John          Satish        Kevin
1                 2             3             4 


#Data and code

list_data <- list(letters = c("A","C","E","H"),names = c("Kim","John","Satish","Kevin"),numbers = 1:4)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Text Mining"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("NLP Tree", tabName = "NLP")
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "NLP",
          fluidRow(
            tabBox(width = 12,height="500",
                   tabPanel("Sentences",
                            uiOutput("nlp_entities")
                   )
            ) 
          )  
        )
      )     
    ) 
  )



 server <- function(input, output) {
    output$nlp_entities <- renderUI({
      a <- lapply(list_data[[1]], function(x) {
         valueBox(x,"names")
     })
    tagList(a)
  }) 
 }
   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate from 1 to the length of sub-list and with each iteration extract wanted information.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$nlp_entities <- renderUI({
        a <- list()
        for(i in seq_len(lengths(list_data)[1])) {
            a[[i]] <- valueBox(lapply(list_data[c(1, 3)], "[[", i), 
                               list_data[[2]][i])
        }
        tagList(a)
    }) 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou,but here i want names to be at "names" place (i.e subtitle of value box).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can i know why have you added those string brackets("[[")

Comment: @anwar it's for `lapply` (works like passing an *extract* function) - there I'm asking *extract i element from the list*.